# Generate a txt file, from another given, with the dates ordered, and those between two other dates given

Tags: java, file, loops, while-loop, localdate

I am trying to make a method that, given an input txt file and two LocalDate dates, return another file with the dates between the two given, and sorted.
I already know how to read the file, create another one, and introduce in the new file the dates sorted. But I have no idea about how to make the dates between the two given. I am trying to do it with while loops.
If you have some idea, it would be amazing to light me the way. I show you the code that already have, thank you.

```
private static File fileGenerator(String f_input, LocalDate Date1, LocalDate date2) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
 FileReader fr=new FileReader (f_input);
 BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(fr);
 File f_output=new File("C:/Users/Ivan/Documents/output_file.txt");
 FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f_ouput);
 BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

 //Here, i create a list where I will drop every line from f_input
 LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
 String line=null;
 while((line=br.readLine())!=null) {
    list.add(line);
 {

 //Now, I sort the list
 Collections.sort(list);

 Iterator iter = list.iterator();
 String c;
 while(iter.hasNext()){
    c=(String) iter.next();
    bw.append(c);
    bw.newLine();
    bw.flush();
 {

 br.close();
 fr.close();
 fw.close();

 return f_ouput;
```

Comment: *But I have no idea about how to narrow them between the given dates.* -- I'm sorry, what does this mean?

Comment: Im sorry for my bad expressions. It means make the dates between the two given.

Comment: You mean the user will input 2 dates and you need to just write only dates that fall in between them to the file?

Comment: Exactly. I just need in the new returned file the dates that fall in between, sorted them.

Comment: In what format are the dates? Could share a few lines of the input file that you are reading?

Comment: Dates are in LocalDate format. I will update with the introduction of the method

Comment: Are they in `mm/dd/yyyy`?, `dd/mm/yyyy`?, `yyyy-mm-dd`?, etc.

Comment: They are in  dd/mm/yyyy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to perform the following: (psuedocode if you like)

1. Convert each string from the file using the following code :

   ```
   DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
   // for example 
   LocalDate test = LocalDate.parse(string_frm_file, formatter);
   ```
2. Now you need to compare that `LocalDate` (here, test) to see if it falls within your range passed in to your method. If it does add it to the list to be written to the file, else ignore it.

   ```
   if (date1.isBefore(test) && date2.isAfter(test)) {
       list.add(test);
   }
   ```

Comment: I done it adapting this code to mine, but tell me that, for example, text "1999,04,22" could not be parsed at index 4.

Comment: I just formatted like "yyyy/MM/dd" and that happened

Comment: Ok now is "formatting", but it tells me Unable to obtain LocalDate from TemporalAccesor: [Year=1999, DayOfMonth=22, MinuteOfHour=4].... MINUTE OF HOUR??

Comment: Ok, now is working. Everything is fine. Thank you so much sir, really appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0):

A predicate is a function that says "is this row allowed". To allow a row, it should return true.

This predicate function can be passed to a collection to filter it.

For example:

```
public static List<Employee> filterEmployees (List<Employee> employees,
                                            Predicate<Employee> predicate)
{
    return employees.stream()
                .filter( predicate )
                .collect(Collectors.<Employee>toList());
}
```

The above example is Java 8 onwards.

Here is a more exhaustive list in this article:
https://www.baeldung.com/java-collection-filtering

I also like Google Guava library's Collections2.filter method mentioned in the above article.

```
Collection<MyClass> result = Collections2.filter(baseCollection, predicate);
```

Of course, still the predicate has to be written to parse the dates from the file and compare them to the input date range.

Comment: Erm.. How does this answer the question?

Comment: The way you, Teddy, are trying to explain this to me is confusing. At least for me, that im just an Engineering student trying to understand hahaha. Thank you by the way.

Comment: @NicholasK I thought OP knows Collections.sort method and was looking for a filtering method in the Collections API :)